# How to not change every div image in my code

Tags: css, html

I am a total beginner and I am trying to Change the Image of a div with css without changing the images of every other div coming after it.

```
    <div>
        <font size="+2">Pflücken</font> <div class="image" onclick="MullClick(1)"> </div>
        <br />
        </div>
        <font size="+2">Blume</font> :<span id="Mull"><b>0</b></span>
        <br />
        <br /><br /><br />
        <br />
        <br /><br /><br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <font size="+3">Blumentopf:</font> <div class="image"  onclick="buyBlume()"></div>
        <br />
        Blumentopf: <span id="Blume">0 </span><br />
        Kosten: <span id="BlumeCost">10 </span><br />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </body>

CSS    
    div.image {
        content:url (Imageurl)
    }
```

I want to change only one image but it changes both images. Is there some way to simply "classify" them so I can only work with one ?

Comment: `div.image:first-child` ? and by the way that's not an image! it's a div with a class name of `image`

Comment: Just need to learn the difference in your [hooks](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: FWIW, [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) tag is deprecated and should not be used in new code.

Comment: just do it with different classes